# Retornar dados dentro de um período de tempo

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte `query`:

```
SELECT raddb.FisioterapiaUtente.Id, DataConsulta, Inicio, Fim, raddb.UtentesCD.Utente, nome  
FROM raddb.FisioterapiaUtente LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.usuarios ON raddb.usuarios.id = raddb.FisioterapiaUtente.Fisioterapeuta
LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.UtentesCD ON raddb.UtentesCD.IdUtente = raddb.FisioterapiaUtente.Utente WHERE DataConsulta BETWEEN '2019-10-26' AND '2019-11-25'
```

Pretendo pesquisar sempre este período (entre 26 e 25 de cada mês) ao longo ano, então o problema está em definir as datas de forma dinâmica.

Comment: Faça um `WHERE` com uma condição na coluna de data do seu registro. Fica: leia sobre o `BETWEEN`.

Comment: @Woss Sim, eu sei isso o problema é como defino sempre o dia 26 do mês anterior de forma automática e o dia 25 do mês atual de forma automática.

Comment: Hum, então poderia deixar mais claro isso na pergunta. Consegue [edit] e colocar um exemplo da condição que precisa ter, mesmo com as datas fixas e descrever que o problema está apenas em definir as datas dinamicamente?

Comment: @Woss  editei a pergunte como sugeriu, assim fica mais claro o meu problema. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estivermos no mês 12, irá pesquisar entre 26/10 e 25/11, pois irá pegar a primeira data diminuindo 2 meses da atual e a segunda data 1 mes da atual.

```
SELECT raddb.FisioterapiaUtente.Id,
       DataConsulta,
       Inicio, 
       Fim, 
       raddb.UtentesCD.Utente, 
       nome  
  FROM raddb.FisioterapiaUtente LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.usuarios ON raddb.usuarios.id = raddb.FisioterapiaUtente.Fisioterapeuta
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.UtentesCD ON raddb.UtentesCD.IdUtente = raddb.FisioterapiaUtente.Utente 
 WHERE DataConsulta BETWEEN SUBDATE(concat(year(current_date()),'/',month(CURRENT_DATE()),'/','26'), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND
                            SUBDATE(concat(year(current_date()),'/',month(CURRENT_DATE()),'/','25'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```